# TFS code review alerts

Tags: tfs-alerts

I want to change my TFS code review alerts so I am only notified about a change to it at the time that I am added to the review, and not every time other people who are also on the review are posting comments.

I tried changing the alert filters to:

My Review Status = Added

When I try to save this filter I get a weird error that makes no sense.

Failed to save one or more alerts:

Could not parse the xpath expression for the alert. Please verify your filter conditions. Details: 'Reviewers/Reviewer[@Name="@@MyDisplayName@@"]@Status' has an invalid token.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seeing the same issue.  The trigger seems to be the "My Review Status" criteria, as it doesn't work with either an '=' or '<>' condition.  I found this, but because '=' is also broken I don't think it's related: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786728/code-reviews-alerts-no-longer-working-after-update-3-rc1-applied

Comment: Created this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2923339/cannot-create-a-code-review-alert-that-uses-the-field-my-review-status

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved in TF Server 2015 Update 2.1:

[Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2.1 details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6da268be-c72c-43a5-95ad-9f28c1ef400c)

- Fixed bugs

  - Alerts:

    - You may not consistently receive code review alerts.
    - If your team project name contains a space, your notifications may have invalid links.

My team recently upgraded to Update 3 from Update 1 and [the issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2923339/cannot-create-a-code-review-alert-that-uses-the-field-my-review-status) is now resolved.